# Why can't you see computer behind a router?

Tags: computer-networks

I understand the basics of networking(DNS,DHCP,IP,MAC, etc.).

I have installed a router and plugged my computer into the router.
On the other end of the router the cable goes somewhere to a switch(I think). And then to internet. But on the same network my neighbour is also connected. Now my neighbour and I tried to ping his computers but I cannot seem to find it. Why is that ?

Answer (score 2):

When you install a new router and plug various devices to it, all plugged in devices got totally new set of private IP address. Your router act as Network Address Translation (NAT) server. All of devices behind router, are on different private network. It also possible that your device and neighbour's device may have same private IP addresses because your neighbour would be getting IP address from different router or DHCP server.

Comment: hi i have read the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation about NAT. What i understand from it you have on one side of the router address and on the other side it gets address from somewhere else and redirects them ? is this correct. If this is the case i can understand it is not possible to see it, or is it possible in another way?